# Is it feasible to use SOLR as non-relational database when plugged in with Zoie?

Tags: database, solr, nosql

Title says all. We have roughly 10 million items that constantly changes. It has roughly 30 - 50 fields that we may search on. Some of the items might have a few additional fields which is not generic enough (so that we can apply them on all items), but in general this is something we could live with.

I understand that Zoie is a solution for near-real-time search and indexing based on Lucene. It also has a plugin for SOLR. Upon first try, we had some minor issues, but overall I don't see any problem with using it as a non-relational database solution. Of course, we have to sacrifice many features, e.g. constraints, transactions, unique key generation, etc. But compared with what we get, these can also be compensated or patched, one way or another.

So, I guess my question is, does anyone really have any real problem with using such combo as a database in a serious app?

Comment: constantly means real time scenario?

Comment: I would say near-real-time. sub-second latency should be ok. Anything greater than several seconds is definitely not tolerable.

Answer (score 0):

Constantly means real time scenario or what are the requirements?

Take a look into: http://wiki.apache.org/solr/NearRealtimeSearchTuning

I would also take a look into Solandra + ElasticSearch too!